# "Rails.root" behavior different in development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

After migrating to rails 6.1.3, it seems that result of Rails.root in production is now:

```
#<Pathname:/app>
```

but in development mode Rails.root gives:

```
#<Pathname:/.../my_folder>
```

Now, all my links like this one are broken in production

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'services', 'printers', 'fonts', 'Roboto-Thin.ttf')
```

I can't find any solution now to have a behavior working locally and in production.

Does anybody knows how to set Rails.root on production ?

Comment: can you post some info about your dev and prod envs? OS, ruby version, etc...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reactivity :-)

I found the solution, and we have been to a wrong issue in facts...

With heroku all your app is on app folder. When I upgrade to Rails 6, I change some folder names relating to Zetiwerk:Error (names of classes should match with folder names).

.ttf files were used in a module, and where added to .gitignore sevent month ago. As the folder name never change, I think the files where still take into account.

After migration, error was something like this: missing file on 'app/app/services/printers/roboto.tff' This was the beginning of wrong issue !